# How to access local file system through flask RESTful API deployed in Google App Engine

Tags: python

I have developed a Flask RESTful API and deployed in Google App Engine. API's endpoint parameter is the folder path.I can not figure out that how my RESTful API will access my local file system.

Comment: What have you tried to figure it out?

Comment: code on server can't access folder on your local computer. You would have to run local www/ftp/ssh server and then code on server can connet to local  www/ftp/ssh server to get local file. But your local server has to be accessible from internet - and it can be problem because it can be blocked by router of your internet provider.

Comment: Let me clear about this I have developed a RESTful API using Flask which will in turn invoke another python code. The HTTP request endpoint for the API is http://<domain>/RESTfulAPI/DirectoryPath="<absolute folder path>(c://folder1/folder2)". My API backend program will fetch the files from this directory path and it will process those files. When I am running the api locally It is working fine. But after deploying the RESTful API in Google App Engine it is unable to find the folder (which is in my local machine). How to solve this issue?

Comment: Hey @furas can you please explain the process in details.

Comment: server has access only to folders on server. It doesn't have access to folder on your computer or my computer on any other person on the world. I think you should send data from your file instead of path. Even if you send path then it would have to somehow send this file from your computer to server.